# Select only the latest version of the data with SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one containg offer information and the other containg products
something like this:

```
           OFFER                                 PRODUCTS
ID      Number      Version          poID      offer_id     Product       how_many
==========================            ========================================
1          123       1                1         1              Apple        1
2          123       2                2         1              Banana       2
3          124       1                3         1              Orange       1
                                      4         2              Apple        1
                                      5         2              Banana       2
                                      6         2              Orange       2
                                      7         2              Kiwi         1
                                      8         3              Apple        2
                                      9         3              Banana       3
```

I would like a list of how many products that are currently offered. 
Since OFFER(id = 2) is an update of (id = 1) only (id = 2) should be counted.

How should I best query this?

Comment: can you post the desired results.. the question is confusing..

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get all the latests offers:

```
select o.id
from offer o
where version = (select max(version)
                 from offer o2
                 where o2.number = o.number);
```

Based on the above you can then get all the products:

```
select p.*
from products p
where offer_id in (select o.id
                   from offer o
                   where version = (select max(version)
                                    from offer o2
                                    where o2.number = o.number));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE offer_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM offer)
```

or, if you prefer the join syntax

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id FROM offer) o ON p.offer_id = o.id
```

Edit (still not completely sure this is what you want without seeing your desired results)

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN offer o on p.offer_id = o.id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT number, max(version) 
 FROM offer
 GROUP BY number
) oMax ON o.number = oMax.number AND o.version = oMax.version
```

Comment: This will not return the desired result.

Comment: your subquery does not produce the correct result, he's looking for the `id` with the `MAX(version)`

Comment: could be I read the question wrong, but as I understand it, the OP wants all the products with offer_id = 3. I suppose it could be interpreted that he wants apple and banana from offer 3, and kiwi and orange from offer 2, in which case you're right, it wouldn't return that..

Comment: No, he wants products with offer_ids = 2,3

Answer (score 0):

If `id` and `version` correlate:

```
select sum(how_many) from products p
join offer on p.offer_id=offer.id
join (
    select number, max(version) version from offer group by number  
) x 
on offer.id=x.id and offer.version = x.version
```

Comment: This will only work if an offer with a higher vesion number is guaranteed to have a higher id as well.

Comment: usually this kind of constraint is given. however i updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select [list columns here]
from products p
join (select offernumber, max(id) as ID from offer group by offernumber) a
    on a.id = p.offer_id
```

If you need addtional columns from offer other than the offernumber and the id:

```
select [list columns here]
from products p
join (select offernumber, max(id) as ID from offer group by offernumber) a
    on a.id = p.offer_id
join offer o on o.id = a.id
```